# Git repository in Dropbox syncing to Windows and OS X - Line endings

Tags: git, newline

I've read the article here: https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings.

My situation is my repository is synced with Dropbox as well. This means when I switch between my Windows and OS X machines, I don't have to pull from the online repo. But the issue here is the line endings.

Can I force either platforms to use LF or CRLF? Will there be any side effects? E.g. Instruct Sublime Text to use LF even on Windows.

Is there a way to kinda patch and convert all files to LF or CRLF once the decision is made to use one type of line ending?

I'm trying to avoid changing my workflow as build and localhost have been set up on this directory structure.

Thanks!

Comment: many advanced text editors (e.g. UltraEdit, Notepad++) in Windows platform supports Mac OS X's line endings.

Answer (score 1):

The platform as a whole cannot be forced to use different line endings. But most of the tools you are using on a platform can or they handle all types of line endings equally.

As far as bulk conversion of line endings is concerned, the GitHub article you're linking to gives instructions on that. Read the [Re-normalizing a repository](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings#re-normalizing-a-repository) part.

Side-effects could exist and be very nasty if you don't setup all the used tools on all used platforms to work well with the chosen line ending type. You could for example run into trouble with the programming language of your choice and cross-platform code – e. g. in PHP the constant [`PHP_EOL`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php#constant.php-eol) containing platform's line ending will no longer match the line endings in your code, which requires some attention when using multiline strings.

Comment: Thanks for the note on PHP_EOL!